# Getting an error "unbound prefix" in android config.xml

Tags: android, cordova

so I'm trying to set up an app link to my application but I'm getting this error when trying to compile.

I'm using cordova to write the application.

```
:app:mergeDebugResourcesC:\projectPath\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml:23: AAPT: error: unbound prefix.

C:\projectPath\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml:23: error: unbound prefix.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

//config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="rezz" android:scheme="rezz" />
    </intent-filter>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
</widget>
```

Basically its due to the 'intent-filter' setting, I need to add something to that but don't really know what. It works properly if I remove that setting.

Comment: The xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" attribute should be added to the root <widget> tag inside the config.xml if you want to use <tag android:abc>.

Comment: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config/issues/24 may this is helps to u.

Comment: That fixed the issue thanks! But I don't seem to be able to open the application from a browser. I'm just putting on a browser the "rezz://rezz/" URL. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: @BhupatBheda any ideas?

Comment: I had to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` in my *root* config.xml, rather than the config.xml which was reported in the error message. That fixed it.